# Is it possible to have data loss converting binary data to Windows-1252 encoding?

Tags: c#, string, text, encoding, binary

I understand that the best way to convert binary data to a textual format is to use base64 encoding. UTF-8 can result in lossiness. But as I was investigating this, I found that Windows-1252 encoding does not seem to result in data loss by way of its design.

I provide a lot more context in my [blog post here](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx).

At the end, I provide some reasons why I still wouldn't store binary data as a Windows-1252 string. But I'm curious if there's an actual data-loss scenario there I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT put binary data in a string, because binary data can contain bytes with values below 32.
This has nothing to do with the encoding of the string.

And I'm not sure where you got the "UTF-8 is lossy, but CP1252 is not" from. But I'm not sure I want to know.

Comment: Did you *read* his blogpost? He performed an experiment that appeared to show that all bytes 0-255 can be round-tripped through Windows-1252.

Comment: I read his question/post, more along the lines of "You encounter a system that, for whatever bizarre reason, is currently storing binary data by converting to a string using windows 1252. It would appear that, whilst certainly not the right way to do things, this won't have actually corrupted the data, so I don't need to set the priority of a bug fix to the highest level (as I would if UTF-8 was being used, because that certainly can cause corruption). Is this analysis correct?"

Comment: I read it more along the way of "can you give me a good reason not to do this, otherwise I might?", and expecting answers with examples like, "yeah, don't store it in an XML file, because you might mysteriously lose all bytes with value 13", silly stuff like that. His blog, where he acts surprised at finding that a UTF-8 reader gets confused by feeding it binary data didn't instil much confidence either.

Comment: Damien is spot on. I'm not looking for a reason to do this. I want to make sure I have a clear explanation why not to do this because I some times encounter code like that.

Comment: @Haacked The reason not to do it is because text encoding is a way to store text, not binary data! As you saw in your blog, trying to use an UTF-8 decoder to put random bytes into a string results in the illegal UTF-8 byte sequences being translated into a legal character. Because that's the way it works! Now using a Windows-1252 decoder doesn't have that problem as badly, because Windows-1252 doesn't have illegal byte sequences, but it does have a number of undefined character values (0x81 for instance), and the library doesn't guerantee that those undefined values can be round-trippable.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the problem is better thought of if you consider that you aren't converting `binary data` to `CP1252` but in `C#` you are converting `binary data` as `CP1252` to `UTF-16`, so the question is would `CP1252` -> `UTF-16` -> `CP1252` guarantee no polymorphic mutations.

The .net text encoder does a best fit on `UTF-16` -> `CP1252` that sounds iffy at best, while it may test okay, there aren't many scenarios in which you could do anything with that `UTF-16` string in the middle that would still guarantee no data loss, and it's much less efficient than a byte array.